# command line "*" operand not working in postfix notation c program

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, multiplication, postfix-notation

I have a C program that converts postfix notation into an answer, so for "2 2 +" it would print 4, for "2 4 + 3 / 6 +" it would print 8. However, when I do "2 4 ^ 2 * 5 % 2", it has a problem with the "*" since it take the bin I'm in to account and adds file names into the command line arguments. I'll attach my code that I have going, but my question is, is there anyway to avoid having the "*" in the command line mess with the test of the arguments.

PS, someone told me that by putting the * in quotation marks in the command line, like so:

```
./a.out 2 4 ^ 2 "*" 5 % 2 -
```

would work, and it hasn't. so any ideas around this?

My code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct stack {

    int top;
    int items[100];

} stack;

void initializeStack(stack* p);
void push(stack* p, int val);
int pop(stack* p);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i, a, b;
    int val = 0;
    stack ph;
    initializeStack(&ph);

    //for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
        //printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "*") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = a*b;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "/") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = b/a;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "+") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = a+b;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = b-a;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "^") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = (int)pow(a,b);
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "%") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = b%a;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else {
            push(&ph, atoi(argv[i]));
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", pop(&ph));

    return 0;
}

void initializeStack(stack* p) {
    p->top = 0;
}

void push(stack* p, int val) {
    p->top++;
    p->items[p->top] = val;
}

int pop(stack* p) {
    int y;
    y = p->items[p->top];
    p->items[p->top] = 0;
    (p->top)--;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Your program looks fine and appears to work correctly in a test I just made here.

Comment: Double-quotes may still expand wildcards in some shells, try single quotes.

Comment: `'*'` and `if(strcmp(argv[i], "'*'") == 0) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: \*. Much like in C you need to provide an escape character for arguments that the command line recognizes. (where "\" is the escape).

Disclaimer: \ is for GNU/Linux anyway (and as a side note, also for Stack answers... You need two \'s in order to print one \).